# как последнее значение таблицы из sqlite передать в переменной с#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

помогите пжс!!
у меня в таблице записаны несколько колонок

```
id   name
1     AA
2     SS
```

мне нужно передать значение последной ячейки в переменной?

Comment: ну и проблема то в чем?

Comment: я только начинаю программировать, не знаю как это сделать

Comment: сами что пытались сделать? Есть какие то наработки? Гуглили вашу проблему? Какие то примеры кода пробовали? Покажите, что вы сами сделали, чтобы себе помочь.

Comment: У строк нет порядка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB_NAME = @"C:\print&scan\Database1.db";
if (DB_NAME == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Open an existing database or Create a new database");
    return;
}
this.dataSet = new DataSet();
String sql_con = new SQLiteConnection(
    String.Format("Data Source={0};New=False;Version=3", DB_NAME));
// SQLiteCommand tx = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM price ");
SQLiteCommand tx = new SQLiteCommand(
    "SELECT id FROM price ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1", sql_con);

tx.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
tx.Connection.Open();
SQLiteDataReader tx1 = tx.ExecuteReader();
if (tx1.HasRows)
{
    while (tx1.Read())
    {
        string yy = tx1[0].ToString();
        int xx = Convert.ToInt32(yy);
        xx++;// увеличения  
        label7.Text = xx.ToString();
    }
}
```